# How to use fixtures within setup_function and teardown_function in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test where I need setup/teardown to be run for each test function:

```py
class A:
    def setup(self):
        return 'setup'

    def teardown(self):
        return 'teardown'

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def a():
    return A()

def setup_function(a):
    logger.info(a.setup())

def test_a(a):
    logger.info('test_a')

def teardown_function(a):
    logger.info(a.teardown())
```

`a` contains the function `test_a` and not the fixture in setup_function and teardown_function. How can I access the fixture `a` within these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that another fixture could be used to wrap the test function:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def a():
    return A()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def wrapper(a):
    a.setup()
    yield
    a.teardown()

def test_a(wrapper):
    logger.info('test_a')
```